# How to order by a date part?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, lambda

I have a `DataColumn` of `DateTime` datatype and I want to order by the year in descending order followed by the month in descending order.

Here's what I tried:

```
table.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Field<DateTime>("MaxDateTaken").Year)
    .ThenByDescending(o => o.Field<DateTime>("MaxDateTaken").Month)
```

I get an invalid cast error because both `Year` and `Month` are int datatypes, but I'm specifying `DateTime` in the `<>`

Any ideas?

Comment: If you order DateTimes in descending order, are they not by year and then by month, just as you say you want?

Comment: @DOK - Just wanted it to be sorted by year and month, but not day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't get a cast error because of that - are you sure that field is *really* a `DateTime`?

It sounds like you *really* just want

```
table.AsEnumerable()
     .OrderByDescending(o => o.Field<DateTime>("MaxDateTaken"))
```

anyway, given that ordering by the year and the month descending is basically ordering by the date descending, except it doesn't do anything with the "day" part. Do you really not want to include the "day" part in your ordering?

Comment: Oh, looks like it is a string now... You're right.  I guess I need to convert it to DateTime type within the OrderByDescending() call.

Comment: @subt13: That would certainly explain it. If you can *possibly* change the data type in the source, that would be much neater than parsing it in the client, which is the other obvious possibility.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's coming down from SQL server as part of a dynamic pivot query, so I cannot change the type, I guess.

Comment: @subt13: Can you not change the query? How is it stored on SQL Server? You should avoid this sort of conversion as much as possible, IMO.

Comment: I wanted to avoid this as well, because it has created a lot of extra work for me, however, I would have to rewrite the cross tab procedure to allow me to provide data types for each column involved.  This would be much harder than just doing what I did below.

Comment: @subt13: It sounds to me like you're avoiding doing the *logical* thing in order to make a quick fix. That may save time in the short term, but it's adding technical debt. If this is a short-lived project, that makes sense - but keep an eye on it.

Comment: Yes, you're 100% correct.  I will bring it up for discussion at work tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you ignoring the day part? It could get simpler:

```
table = table.AsEnumerable()
   .OrderByDescending(o => DateTime.Parse(o.Field<string>("MaxDateTaken")))
```

Comment: Yes, I agree it is an odd case.  I do not want the day portion to affect the sort.  I have a specific business rule to order in this way.  That's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like this:

```
table = table.AsEnumerable()
   .OrderByDescending(o => DateTime.Parse(o.Field<string>("MaxDateTaken")).Year)
   .OrderByDescending(o => DateTime.Parse(o.Field<string>("MaxDateTaken")).Month)
```